# Server supports TLS1.3 but refuses 1.2

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache2, openssl

I have the following Problem:
Im hosting my website and some tools on a VServer running Ubuntu 18.04 behind an apache2.
Some people told me that they can't reach my website and I tracked it down with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest to being probable that my server supports TLS1.3 but not TLS1.2:
[SSLLabs Protocol Configuration (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlT53.png)
Im a bit confused with that, my `openssl version` tells me: `OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018`.
I have the following in my apache configuration: `SSLProtocol -ALL +TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.3` which should enable TLS1.2 and 1.3.

Do you have any idea / clue for me where i have a twist in my configuration?
It seems strange to me that TLS1.3 works but 1.2 does not, woulnd't it make more send if it would be the other way around?

Thank you!
Johannes

Comment: Please provide your configuration. We can't tell you anything without seeing it.

Comment: What kind of configuration do you need from me? 
Entire V-Host? Some SSL-Config?